# Rotate svg image inside table, but td doesn't follows height and width

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-transforms

I'm learning CSS now, but I'm kinda lost at this point. What I want to achieve is a 3x4 `table` with SVGs in it. I have to rotate 90 degrees the image, but after that I show below what happens. The problem is that the `td` inside the `table` doesn't follow the width. I don't know if it's a basic behavior of tables, or something, but it took hours of research and didn't find anything.
[image: Problem]

Here's what I have:

```
.game img {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.game {
  margin: auto;
}

.game td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rotated elements take the space they *would* take *without* the rotating (which is also apparent in the image you posted), which *can* result in overlaps.

Possibly solutions would be 1.) to give a `min-width` to the `td`s which is equal to the height of the images, or 2.) to change the image(s) themselves to be square (height = width), with the additional areas being transparent if needed, or 3.) save the image inthe rotated state and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, my first language isn't english :) .

Solution 1 mostly works, but the height of the cell is still too big. I have ```display : inline-block``` for the table, and because of it I cannot set ```max-height```. 
Sokution 2 and 3 are not an option, because there are a large number of svg files in the project.