# Rotated image not shown correctly in table

Tags: html, css, itext7

I am using Itext7 HTMLToPDF to convert an HTML page to a PDF document. I had an issue that the image is not rotated. See [Itext7 HTML2PDF - Picture not rotated in PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67920328/itext7-html2pdf-picture-not-rotated-in-pdf-file/67962719?noredirect=1#comment120156523_67962719) for more information.

One suggestion is: "*Another option could be just reading the image and the rotation flag, and rotating the image and replacing the image contents in place (so that we replace the original image with its exact copy except that no rotation flags are used, i.e. image is rotated if needed before removing the flag), e.g. by placing the Base64-encoded value into the src attribute.*"

So, I decided to implement this solution.

Removing the rotation flag from a JPG file is no problem. That works fine. I save the file under a new name. I use CSS to mention the rotation:

```
.Rotate_Image1 {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                -moz-transform:    rotate(90deg);
                -ms-transform:     rotate(90deg);
                -o-transform:      rotate(90deg);
                transform:         rotate(90deg);
                width:             300px;
                height:            533.333333333333px;
              }
```

And I use it in a table:

```
<td width=80%><img class="Rotate_Image1" src="C:\Users\WILLEM~1\ONEDRI~1\BACKUP~1\Foto's\JA0E2A~1\20E5E4~1\202210~1.JPG" width="300" height="533.333333333333">
</td>
```

But the picture does not have the proper orientation. See this:
[image]

My question is how to solve this issue. On [Rotate svg image inside table, but td doesn't follows height and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64526260/rotate-svg-image-inside-table-but-td-doesnt-follows-height-and-width) it is mentioned that "*Rotated elements take the space they would take without the rotating (which is also apparent in the image you posted), which can result in overlaps.*" And that is exactly the issue I have.

By the way: the width should always be 300, so that is why the height has a 'strange' value.

Feedback is appreciated and with kind regards,
TheStingPilot

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to solve this issue.

I created a square box:

```
If ($Height -gt $Width) {$Width = $Height}
```

I created the CSS:

```
    $CSS        += ".Rotate_Image$valCounter {`n"
    $CSS        += "                -webkit-transform: rotate($($Rotation)deg);`n"
    $CSS        += "                -moz-transform:    rotate($($Rotation)deg);`n"
    $CSS        += "                -ms-transform:     rotate($($Rotation)deg);`n"
    $CSS        += "                -o-transform:      rotate($($Rotation)deg);`n"
    $CSS        += "                transform:         rotate($($Rotation)deg);`n"
    $CSS        += "                width:             $($Width)px;`n"
    $CSS        += "                height:            $($Height)px;`n"
    $CSS        += "                object-fit:        contain;`n"
    $CSS        += "                max-width:         100%;`n"
    $CSS        += "                max-height:        100%;`n"
    $CSS        += "              }`n`n"
    $ClassText = "class=$([char]34)Rotate_Image$valCounter$([char]34)"
```

`object-fit:        contain;` did the trick.

I am happy now. :-)

With kind regards,
TheStingPilot